# Adding new key value pair to existing json in oracle sql

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I'm trying to add new key-pair at particular position to existing json in the table

I tried searching but didn't find any solution to this.

Existing json-

```
{"clienIds":["485","19"],"id":"3725","summary":{"sections":[],"referenceData":{}}}
```

Json I want-

```
{"clienIds":["485","19"],"id":"3725","summary":{"sections":[],"referenceData":{},"type":"abc"}}
```

Comment: Which Oracle version are you using? (`select version from product_component_version where product like 'Oracle%';` will tell you)

Comment: Version is 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no difference between

```
'{"clienIds":["485","19"],"id":"3725","summary":{"sections":[],"referenceData":{},"type":"abc"}}'
```

and

```
'{"clienIds":["485","19"],"id":"3725","summary":{"type":"abc","sections":[],"referenceData":{}}}'
```

Why not just

```
regexp_replace(json,'("summary":\{)(.*)', '\1"type":"abc",\2')
```

Comment: I need something like this "referenceData":{},"type":"abc"}}' not the way you mentioned "referenceData":{}},"type":"abc"}'

Comment: Edited answer matching your changed question.

Comment: It added new key and value but double quotes being removed summary. json is not getting parsed. It is coming as:    summary":{"type":"abc","sections":[],"referenceData":{}}}